# compilation error in src/libdyld/MachOObject.cpp; compiling darling

Tags: c++, compilation

I was compiling darling and it failed when compiling MachOObject.cpp in libdyld

errors I got

```
MachOObject.cpp:534:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
MachOObject.cpp:534:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
```

The compiler's errors were about this

```
bool MachOObject::lookupDyldFunction(const char* name, void** addr)
{
LOG << "lookupDyldFunction: " << name << std::endl;

*addr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, name);

if (!*addr)
    *addr = (void*) (void (*)()) []() { LOG << "Fake dyld function called\n"; };

return (*addr) != 0;
```

}

note that that was in a void function and the function in a namespace and this was not written by myself

#### **read the whole thing and you will see that this is in c++**

all related code(bulk removed)

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=j6kkkVee

the whole program at github

https://github.com/LubosD/darling

Comment: by the way you used c++0x and you ment to use c==11?`right`

Comment: i had to update the alternatives for g++ to point to clang++ because the commands i was told to run by the programmer diden't work or cmake may have been broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the code is C++11 code, the `Fake dlyd function` is a lambda, and is only supported from clang 3.1 and onwards and g++ 4.5 and newer. Mind you I could not compile an scce using the g++ 4.6.2 shipped with my system.

Based on the readme and the documentation on how to build the code you need to use clang 3.1 or newer, and it must compile using the `-std=c++11` flag. If you're using a compiler that doesn't support that syntax in it's entirety (like, it appears, the compiler you're using), then you will see this error.

In this case, you could make a minor modification to the code to move the dummy function outside the method and just make a reference to it so that it would compile, but this means that you're still using an untested compiler and one that the developer has not called out as a supported mechanism.

the scce for this would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

bool lookupDyldFunction(const char* name, void** addr)
{
    std::cerr << "lookupDyldFunction: " << name << std::endl;

    *addr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, name);

    if (!*addr)
        *addr = (void*) (void (*)()) []() { std::cerr << "Fake dyld function called\n"; };

    return (*addr) != 0;
}
```

compiled using g++:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ g++ -std=c++0x -c lookup.cpp
lookup.cpp: In function ‘bool lookupDyldFunction(const char*, void**)’:
lookup.cpp:12:26: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
lookup.cpp:12:26: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘void’
```

compiled using clang++ (5.0, on a mac; I don't have a new linux clang ATM):

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.78) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -c lookup.cpp
$
```

i.e. compilation succeeded.

Note that there is nothing in the [CMakeList.txt](https://github.com/LubosD/darling/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file that specifies/requires a compiler; it just makes sure that the `-std=c++11` is passed to the compiler.

Comment: Ok, the code *requires* clang3.1 or newer *and* be compiled with -std=c++11, which allows the inline function definition. I'll update the answer

Comment: this is very different `Linking CXX shared library libSystem.so    
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lssl    
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)    
make[2]: *** [src/libSystem/libSystem.so] Error 1    
make[1]: *** [src/libSystem/CMakeFiles/System.dir/all] Error 2    
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: source straight from dir so you can quickly test as I have already compiled half of it (http://www.mediafire.com/?26p31yt1qq8yyu6)

Comment: clang is only 3.2 for Linux and the programmer told me i would have to use clang

Comment: This error looks like you don't have libssl installed, or clang can't find it. I don't know what distro you're using, but there's documentation for [building properly on ubuntu](http://darling.dolezel.info/en/Build/Ubuntu).